# Print if the field starts with a specific string using awk

Tags: awk

I have a list like this in chrs.txt file:

```
chr22
chr21
chrUn_gl000225
chrUn_gl000222
chrM
```

the result I want:

```
chr22
chr21
```

I want to print lines if they do not include chrM and chrUn. So I want to filter string chrM and strings including chrUn. To do so I tried codes below but I could only filter chrM.

```
awk '($1 != "chrM" && $1 != "chrUn")' chrs.txt
awk '($1 != "chrM" && $1 != "/^chrUn/")' chrs.txt
awk '($1 != "chrM" && $1 != "chrUn_*")' chrs.txt
```

If you could help I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need is:

```
awk '!/^chr(Un|M)/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Also grep can do that.

```
grep -Ev '^chr(Un|M)' file
```

GNU ed(1)

```
printf '%s\n' 'v/^chr\(Un\|M\)/p' | ed -s file
```

Answer (score 1):

awk:

```
awk '$0!~/^chr(Un|M)/'
```

sed:

```
sed -rne '/^chr(Un|M)/!p'
```

grep:

```
grep -Ev "^chr(Un|M)"
```

bash:

```
for LINE in $(<your_file.txt); do [[ $LINE =~ ^chr(Un|M) ]] || echo $LINE ; done
```

You should use one of the first three option since they are more portable across differente shell.

Comment: Or `sed -E '/^chr(Un|M)/d'` (Worth noting that `-r` is a non-standard but common extension to `sed`. Sometimes `-E` will do the same thing (Use extended instead of basic regular expressions) if your version doesn't support `-r`, and I *think* it's POSIX these days.).

Comment: @Shawn -r is GNU sed only. -E is newer versions of GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed. Neither are POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you can do the comparison like this (assuming `line` contains a single line of the file, i.e. I've excluded the loop over the file's lines here):

```
if [[ $line != chrUn* ]] && [[ $line != chrM* ]]; then
    echo $line
fi;
```